# Difference of dates between two dates starting everytime at first row date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this

I got difference from consecutive dates but I want to calculate difference of dates starting every time at 1. like (1-2 and 1-3 again 1-4)

```
ChildID   ID      Date
1         4    2005-12-07 00:00:00.000
1         3    2005-11-07 00:00:00.000
1         2    2005-10-09 00:00:00.000
1         1    2005-04-09 00:00:00.000
```

Expected

```
ChildID   ID      Date                         Difference
1         4    2005-12-07 00:00:00.000            243 days (1-4)
1         3    2005-11-07 00:00:00.000            207 days (1-3)
1         2    2005-10-09 00:00:00.000            183 days (1-2)
1         1    2005-04-09 00:00:00.000            NULL
```

Comment: And many of them are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.

Comment: Using Microsoft SQL T SQL

Comment: Most people here want formatted text instead of images.

Comment: Can u add expected output sample data please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) SQL2012:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, FIRST_VALUE(DATECOL) OVER(ORDER BY ID),  DATECOL) AS DIFF ...
FROM ...

2) If ID column has unique values:

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, (SELECT A.DATECOL FROM TABLE1 A WHERE A.ID=1), B.DATECOL) AS DIFF ...
FROM TABLE1 B ...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: This one worked Though DateDiff(day,First_Value(Date) Over (Partition by childid order by Date asc),Date ) as Datedif1

Comment: @Toby Speight: Could you please check Sql Server's documentation for datediff and first_value functions? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by simple query

```
SELECT t1.*, datediff(day, t2.date, t1.date) AS DateDifference
FROM dbo.your_table AS t1
INNER JOIN dbo.your_table AS t2 ON t1.childId = t2.id
```

**Update: Add full example**

```
declare @temp table(childId int, id int, date datetime)

insert into @temp values(1,4,'2005-12-07 00:00:00.000')
insert into @temp values(1,3,'2005-11-07 00:00:00.000')
insert into @temp values(1,2,' 2005-10-09 00:00:00.000')
insert into @temp values(1,1,'2005-04-09 00:00:00.000')


SELECT t1.*, datediff(day, t2.date, t1.date) AS DateDifference
FROM @temp AS t1
INNER JOIN @temp AS t2 ON t1.childId = t2.id
```

Result

```
1   4   2005-12-07 00:00:00.000 242
1   3   2005-11-07 00:00:00.000 212
1   2   2005-10-09 00:00:00.000 183
1   1   2005-04-09 00:00:00.000 0
```

Comment: With join it's giving me 16 records instead of 4

Comment: Are your sure? I tested it, you can see a full example

Comment: I tried worked for single ID. But I have other id's. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Using a Window Function to get the earliest date for this record's child_id:

```
 SELECT datediff(day, min(date_field) OVER (PARTITION BY child_id) - date_field), child_id, id FROM your_table
```

This doesn't take into account that the min(date) for the child_id might not be the record with `id=1`. So if that is a concern, then a subquery solution:

```
SELECT datediff(day, t2.datefield, t1.date_field), child_id, id
FROM your_table t1
    JOIN (SELECT child_id, date_field FROM your_table where id = 1) t2
         ON t1.child_id = t2.child_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

with additional sample data included

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (ChildId INT, Id INT, Date DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @tab
(ChildId, Id, Date)
SELECT 1,4,'2005-12-07 00:00:00.000'
UNION
SELECT 1,3,'2005-11-07 00:00:00.000'
UNION
SELECT 1,2,'2005-10-09 00:00:00.000'
UNION
SELECT 1,1,'2005-04-09 00:00:00.000'
UNION
SELECT 2,1,'2005-12-09 00:00:00.000'
UNION
SELECT 2,2,'2005-12-15 00:00:00.000'
UNION
SELECT 2,3,'2005-12-31 00:00:00.000'

;WITH cteX
AS(
    SELECT
          T.ChildId
        , T.Id
        , T.Date
        , Diff = DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(T.Date) OVER ( PARTITION BY T.ChildId), T.Date)
    FROM @tab T
)
SELECT 
      X.ChildId
    , X.Id
    , X.Date
    , Diff = CASE WHEN X.Diff = 0 THEN NULL ELSE X.Diff END
FROM cteX X
ORDER BY
    X.ChildId , id DESC
```

output is

[image: table]

if you want the final column to look like this

`242 days (1-4)`

then modify `Diff` like so

```
Diff = CAST(CASE WHEN X.Diff = 0 THEN NULL ELSE X.Diff END AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' days' + ' (' + CAST(1 AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + CAST(X.Id AS VARCHAR(2)) + ')'
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for Thanks

Comment: @Hanu Glad I could help.  If you can accept this answer (green tick) and up-vote it that would be appreciated